# Developing apps for Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, mobile

Can we start developing apps for the upcoming windows mobile 7. Are developer tools available?  Do we have to buy the visual studio program for this?

Comment: The development tools comes with a free version of Visual Studio 2010 Express edition; so you won't have to buy VS2010 (or anything, for that matter).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first link is to download the windows phone development tools, which also include Visual Studio 2010 Express and the second is for information on developing for windows phone.

**EDIT** I have changed the links to link to the windows phone beta developer tools.

http://developer.windowsphone.com/windows-phone-7/

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c8496c2a-54d9-4b11-9491-a1bfaf32f2e3&displaylang=en

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402535(VS.92).aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: The link for the WP7 dev tools above is broken (I'm assuming it was linking to the CTP?)

The most recent version of the tools (beta) can be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C8496C2A-54D9-4B11-9491-A1BFAF32F2E3&displaylang=en

I suspect there will likely be a RC release prior to RTM, as there's still room for improvement (like providing a Panorama control)

Comment: @Blakomen Thanks for bringing this to my attention. I have edited the post to link to the proper pages.

Comment: The official developer tools were just released on Sept. 16th!!  You'll need to uninstall the CTP before installing them.  The above links are still valid.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. Yes. No.

**General Information**
http://www.microsoft.com/windowsmobile/en-us/default.mspx
http://developer.windowsphone.com/
http://windowsteamblog.com/Windows_Phone/

**Articles**
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows/WindowsPhoneGame.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/Wp7ViewModel.aspx

**Books**
http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/index.html - FREE!

**Podcasts**
http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=539
http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=542
http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=224
http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=225

**Videos**
http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=172
http://live.visitmix.com/Sessions/Tags/WindowsPhone
http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/WP7/

**Tools**
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c8496c2a-54d9-4b11-9491-a1bfaf32f2e3&displaylang=en

Comment: Excellent info, but really belongs in another community wiki post.  I migrated (and added) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402466/getting-started-with-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 1):

The blog titled 'A Developer’s Roadmap to Windows Phone 7 Launch Timing' from the Official Windows Phone Developer Blog provides some great information. 
If you are a student, you can develop and deploy applications to the Window Phone Marketplace for free via www.dreamspark.com. It is a Microsoft Student Program initiative.

Answer (score 0):

Express version of Visual Studio is free: [Visual Studio 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/downloads/)

Comment: Is the windows mobile marketplace to be in place when the phone launches?

Comment: The marketplace is already up and running.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that you should use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone 7 rather than the Visual Studio 2010 add-in. There are problems with the add-in, not the least of which is that the option to add a service reference to a Windows Phone Application project is conspicuously missing.

http://developer.windowsphone.com is a good place to get started.

The last update to the CTP was in April. Expect some things to change before RTM still.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 7 Mango RC has also been released. You can start developing apps on this. If you have an account in the Windows Phone developer community [App Hub](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/), you will get an update for Mango on your email registered in App Hub account.