# Getting Started with Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna

This is a community wiki list of Windows Phone 7 resources.  Feel free to edit/add/etc.

When posting, please use the friendly format of
`[Actual Name of resource with a link]`
*not*
`[some long URL with no meaning unless I click on it]`

**General Information**
[App hub - central place for windows phone/xbox development tools/tutorials/info](http://create.msdn.com/en-US)
[Windows Phone Home](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/default.aspx)
[Windows Phone Team blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/Windows_Phone/)
[Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402551(v=VS.92).aspx) 
[Class Library Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626516(v=VS.92).aspx)
[Microsoft Patterns & Practices: Windows Phone 7 Developer Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490765.aspx)

**Blogs**
[Den by default: Windows Phone 7](http://dennisdel.com/?tag=windows-phone-7)
[.NET Zone: Windows Phone 7](http://dotnet.dzone.com/category/tags/windows-phone-7-0)
[Shawn Wildermuth: Windows Phone 7](http://wildermuth.com/tags/Windows%20Phone)
[Jeff Blankenburg: 31 Days of Windows Phone](http://jeffblankenburg.com/31daysofwp7/)

**Articles**
[Building a Windows Phone 7 Puzzle Game](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows-phone-7/WindowsPhoneGame.aspx)
[Windows Phone 7 View Model Style Video Player](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows-phone-7/Wp7ViewModel.aspx)
[Perst - a database for Windows Phone 7 Silverlight](http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/andywigley/archive/2010/06/07/perst-a-database-for-windows-phone-7-silverlight.aspx)
Understanding the Windows Phone Application Execution Model, Tombstoning, Launcher and Choosers:
[(part1)](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/07/15/understanding-the-windows-phone-application-execution-model-tombstoning-launcher-and-choosers-and-few-more-things-that-are-on-the-way-part-1.aspx) [(part2)](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/07/16/understanding-the-windows-phone-application-execution-model-tombstoning-launcher-and-choosers-and-few-more-things-that-are-on-the-way-part-2.aspx)  [(part3)](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/07/20/understanding-the-windows-phone-application-execution-model-tombstoning-launcher-and-more-part-3.aspx)
[Performance Tips when creating WP7 apps](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Performance-Tips-when-creating-WP7-apps)
[Windows Phone 7 Live Tile Schedules – How to execute instant Live Tile updates](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/04/03/windows-phone-7-live-tile-schedules-ndash-executing-instant-live-tile-updates)
[Tips to get your Application in the Windows Phone 7 Marketplace ASAP](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/01/18/tips-to-get-your-application-in-the-windows-phone-7-marketplace-asap)
[Checking for Network connectivity in Windows Phone 7 SDK](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/12/09/checking-for-network-connectivity-in-windows-phone-7-sdk)
[Windows Phone 7.1: a Quick Start](http://const.me/articles/win-phone-7/)
[A Simple Multi-Page Windows Phone 7 Phonegap Example](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2011/12/15/a-simple-multi-page-windows-phone-7-phonegap-example.html)

**Books**
[Programming Windows Phone 7](http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/index.html)
[Professional Windows Phone 7 Application Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470891661)
[Pro Windows Phone 7 Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430232196)
[Beginning Windows Phone 7 Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430232161)
[Learning Windows Phone Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449388361)
[Windows Phone 7 Game Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430233060)
[Windows Phone 7 Application Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672332221)
[101 Windows Phone 7 Apps, Volume I: Developing Apps 1-50](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672335522)
[101 Windows Phone 7 Apps, Volume II: Developing Apps 51-101 (Fall 2011)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672335603)

**Podcasts**
[Charlie Kindel on Windows Phone 7](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=539)
[Daniel Egan talks Windows Phone 7 Live at Launch](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=542)
[Windows Phone 7 Series - The Developer Experience with Charlie Kindel](http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=224)
[Charles Petzold on Windows Phone 7 Series](http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=225)

**Videos**
[Windows Phone 7 Jump Start sessions](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/egibson/Windows-Phone-7-Jump-Start-Session-1-of-12-Introduction)
[Colin Melia on Windows Phone 7](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=172)
[Channel9 Content for WIndows Phone](http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/WP7/)

**Developer Tools**
[8 Must-Have Tools for Windows Phone 7 Development](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2012/01/23/8-musthave-tools-for-windows-phone-7-development)
[Windows Phone Developer Tools RTW](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=04704acf-a63a-4f97-952c-8b51b34b00ce&displaylang=en)
[EQATEC Profiler for Windows Phone 7](http://eqatec.com/Profiler)
[BugSense, bug tracking for Windows Phone 7](http://www.bugsense.com/docs/windowsphone)

**Frameworks**
[OpenNETCF.IoC Framework](http://ioc.codeplex.com/)
[Autofac for WP7](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Autofac.Wp7)
[Microsoft Silverlight Analytics Framework](http://msaf.codeplex.com)
[MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/)
[Columbus: Windows Phone 7 MVC framework](http://columbus.codeplex.com)
[Windows Phone MVP](http://windowsphonemvp.codeplex.com/)
[Caliburn.Micro - MVVM framework strongly based on conventions](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Good plan Stan..
Prog guide and Class lib ref added

Comment: Removed "Pivot and Panorama Controls" and "Application Bar Icons", as they are part of the developer tools now.

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Answer (score 23):

**[Windows Phone 7 Jumpstart Training](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jaimer/video-recordings-for-first-windows-phone-7-jumpstart-event)**

Training (Video and PDF) includes:

1. An Introduction to the Windows Phone Platform
2. Game Building on the Windows Phone Platform
3. Advanced Windows Phone Development
4. Selling Your Windows Phone Solutions & Wrap Up

Answer (score 13):

The .NET REST client [RestSharp](https://web.archive.org/web/20101010062421/http://github.com:80/johnsheehan/RestSharp) supports Windows Phone 7. It really simplifies using web services and deserializing the response.

Answer (score 4):

Windows Phone Dev Podcast!!! Don't forget that one! They let you know the latest about the Windows Phone AND they talk to developers (like the guy who made Evernote) about how they made their apps.

Answer (score 4):

I would also add: [30+ Excellent Windows Phone Development Tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/lebanon/excellent-windows-phone-7-development-tutorials)

Answer (score 3):

Here is some information about framework that I had recently published: http://columbus.codeplex.com/

Columbus is MVC framework designed specifically for the Windows Phone 7 platform and supports:

- Strongly typed navigation with history
- View Models that can survive tombstoning
- Asynchronous and cancelable controller actions with execution progress
- Commands (CAB style)
- Multiple navigation frames
- Features to help applications to be complaint with 'Windows Phone 7 Application Certification Requirements'
- Easy integration with [IoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) containers available on the Windows Phone 7 platform (source code solution contains samples demonstrating how to use Columbus with Autofac and Ninject).
- Simplified and testable usage of Choosers

Answer (score 3):

Here is another good intro into phone specific features of silverlight: 
[Andrea Boschin on WP7](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Part-1-Getting-Started.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Plurasight

http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/

this has excellent in depth video tutorials to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

There are few excellent tutorial sets for beginners.

1. [Video series from Bob Tabor for absolute beginners](https://web.archive.org/web/20210508213600/https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-7-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners) These videos are excellent and easy to follow.
2. Once you have started and need help on specific topics consider searching on [GeekChamp](https://web.archive.org/web/20130212010544/http://windowsphonegeek.com:80/articleindex)
3. When you are in a position to publish apps and fine tune things then the [blog series by Jeff Blankenburg](https://web.archive.org/web/20160409030501/http://jeffblankenburg.com/31daysofmango/) is quite useful.