# book for windows phone programming..?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am new to windows phone programming...any good book to start..so that i can learn the essentials...or any other good website to start with???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Started with Windows Phone 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402466/getting-started-with-windows-phone-7)

Answer (score 5):

There is [Petzold's "Programming Windows Phone 7"](http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/), which is available for free.

Windows Phone 7 apps are Silverlight applications (or mobile XNA apps). If you are comfortable with Silverlight, the Petzold book is a good starting point. If you haven't done any Silverlight (or WPF/XAML), then I'd recommend you pick up a good starter book on general Silverlight - most of the techniques learned there will apply to Windows Phone 7 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not a book but the best place to start is the [Windows Phone App Hub](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/)
There are many tutorials, code samples, official design guidelines, forums etc.

Also check out the Windows Phone 7 [developer's guide](http://wp7guide.codeplex.com/) at codeplex.