# Want to start with Windows Phone 7 development

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

As just now, I heard about the Windows Phone 7 development. So I would like to know the following things regarding Windows Phone 7:

1. From where can I start with Windows Phone 7 development? What are the best books/article/code blog/tutorial, etc.
2. Which are the tools I should need/download to start with Windows Phone 7 development?

**Update:**

I found this very much helpful: http://www.devx.com/VS_2010/Article/45898/9851

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Started with Windows Phone 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402466/getting-started-with-windows-phone-7)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Started with Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402466/getting-started-with-windows-phone-7)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get started by downloading the tools and registering to publish here: http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started

There are a lot of very good tutorials out there. I recommend Channel9's [Windows Phone 7 training course](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wp7trainingcourse.aspx) and [Windows Phone 7 for the Absolute Beginner](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-7-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners).

There's also a very good book available as a free PDF download: [Programming Windows Phone 7 by Charles Petzold](http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/).

Comment: Should note that you do not have to register to get the tools and the debugging emulator, but you do need to register to debug against a physical device.  Registration if NOT free. Get the tools and give it a good go before you decide whether you want to spend the money on registration (I registered once I had the main parts of my app finished).

Answer (score 9):

Each of the following contains a long list of useful resources:

[All about Windows Phone (eugenedotnet)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130430021218/http://www.eugenedotnet.com/WindowsPhone7.ashx)
[Windows Phone 7 Resources (indyfromoz)](https://indyfromoz.wordpress.com/windows-phone-7-resources/)
[Mike’s Mega List of Windows Phone 7 Resources (mikeormond)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160112140600/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/07/09/mike-s-mega-list-of-windows-phone-7-resources.aspx)
[Mega List of Windows 7 Phone Resources (Frank La Vigne)](https://web.archive.org/web/20120828034809/http://franksworld.com:80/blog/archive/2010/07/09/12076.aspx)
[Ultimate List of Free Windows Phone 7 Software & Resources (Blake Handler)](https://blakehandler.wordpress.com/2010/04/05/ultimate-list-of-free-windows-phone-7-software-resources-from-microsoft/)
[Windows Phone 7 – List of Tutorials and Resources (onishimura)](https://web.archive.org/web/20120201124401/http://onishimura.com/2010/07/22/windows-phone-7-list-of-tutorials-and-resources/)
[Windows Phone 7 Resources and Links (XDA Developers)](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/windows-phone-7-resources-and-links.711629/)
[The best resources for Windows Phone 7 Development (Mark Kirby)](https://mark-kirby.co.uk/2010/the-best-resources-for-windows-phone-7-development/)
[Windows Phone 7 Developer Resources (Blankenblog)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160308132627/http://jeffblankenburg.com/page/windows-phone-7-resources.aspx)

via http://wpug.net/resources

Once you get past the basics, you may want to have a look at the [Windows Phone 7 Development Best Practices Wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20201109030216/https://wp7dev.wikispaces.com/).

Answer (score 4):

From where I started to learn, here are the links =)

- [Windows Phone 7 development for absolute beginners](https://web.archive.org/web/20101210090547/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/coding4fun/archive/2010/11/12/10090364.aspx)

I use this for reference

- [Windows Phone Development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/) (MSDN)

and this

- [The best resources for Windows Phone 7 Development](https://mark-kirby.co.uk/2010/the-best-resources-for-windows-phone-7-development/)
- [Getting Started with Silverlight and Windows Phone 7 Development](https://timheuer.com/blog/get-started-with-silverlight-for-windows-phone)

Answer (score 2):

If you have C# experience then Windows Phone 7 is easy. Just use MSDN for what is and is not allowed, much the same as a desktop/web C# application using .NET.

If you don't know C# start by learning Visual Studio and C# by building some basic Windows Form applications, get more advanced until you feel comfortable, and then move to Windows Phone 7.

I was one of the showcase application developers from MS so I got dropped in the dark with a short deadline, but once I got it all installed and started working with it MSDN was the best help as there were not many tutorials at that point in time, but if you don't know C# start with Windows and move to phone after as Windows have many more tutorials.