# Windows Phone 7 Response Redirect

Tags: windows-phone-7

Dead simple question, but I'm new so give me a break.

Windows Phone 7. Click on a button and I want to redirect to a new xaml in the code behind.

How do I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to do something like this:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

If you create a new Databound application you'll see a similar thing which also includes an example of passing data to the other page.

If you're  new to the platform you may also benefit from having a look at the answers at [Want to start with Windows Phone 7 development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191756/want-to-start-with-windows-phone-7-development)

BTW. It's Windows PHONE 7, not Windows Mobile.

Comment: Roger on the windows phone not mobile ;)