# Resources for creating a Windows Phone 7 application in VS 2010

Tags: windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Started with Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402466/getting-started-with-windows-phone-7)

I am new to creating Windows Phone apps.

I want to develop my application in Visual Studio 2010 and also I would like some materials (like e-books) for developing for the Windows Phone 7.

Does anyone know of a website for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/

http://wp7dev.wikispaces.com/

are two great resources

Answer (score 1):

Check out the great free eBook from http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the 12 hours of free Jump Start training videos by Rob Miles. http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/egibson/windows-phone-7-jump-start-session-1-of-12-introduction .

They provide an excellent introduction to both Silverlight and XNA. They start right at the very beginning so is the perfect place to start.