# Could someone suggest a tool for programming WP7 apps?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've been planning on programming some WP7 apps, and I am wondering if there is a good tool I should use for such a venture. I'm also looking to get used to the syntax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Started with Windows Phone 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402466/getting-started-with-windows-phone-7)

Answer (score 4):

I guess you mean development tools ? You can  download all you need from http://create.msdn.com/en-US/

What do you mean by syntax? C# is the  language for development on WP7 , you can also choose to use Visual Basic

Comment: Yep. I am trying to bone up on some C#. Thank you for your link!

Answer (score 2):

Try [this link](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started), you'll find the Visual Studio Express edition for WP7, XNA Game Studio, Microsoft Expression Blend for Windows Phone, the WP7 emulator and more! All free.

Posibly you [are going to need a good book](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/10/28/free-ebook-programming-windows-phone-7-by-charles-petzold.aspx) (for free) to start using all this. You can also check the training kit [here](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/wp7_training_kit)...

...and have a good programming time!

Comment: Thanks for the book!  I'd been waiting for them to finalize it