# Really simple windows phone 7 application idea for beginners

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am just a beginner in developing windows phone 7 apps. Can you suggest some ideas or rather exercises that can get me started working on the platform and start building some real applications.

Will really appreciate the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Started with Windows Phone 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402466/getting-started-with-windows-phone-7)

Comment: Nah i don't think so, many beginners face a problem that once they get a grasp of the framework and tools, they just lack on the application ideas they can actually implement in order to strengthen their programming skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, simple games like pong or breakout are always good ways to play around and get used to a new platform. You could also a try writing a simple notepad style app.

If those are more than you'd like to take on just yet, 'guess the number' and other similar games are always good too.

Maybe you could also Google for some simple tutorials and run through them? [This one](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/windows/introduction-to-windows-mobile-7-development/) seems to be a good, if very basic, introduction.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas Keysmack. The link you attached is just a tutorial to get anyone started. But what I am looking is the application ideas that can be implemented.

Comment: I wasn't sure just how much of a beginner you were, so I thought I'd include that in case you needed a head start. 

Another thing you may try is to browse to the iTuines App Store or Android Market and look at apps. See if there are any that look interesting and try to draw inspiration from there.