# What are some performance tips when making Windows Phone 7 applications?

Tags: performance, windows-phone-7

As performance is very important for Windows Phone 7 application development I am starting this question so that we can collect here some helpful performance tips.

**General**:

[Performance Considerations in Applications for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967560%28VS.92%29.aspx)

**Articles**:

[Performance Tips when creating WP7 apps](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Performance-Tips-when-creating-WP7-apps)

[Performance of Windows Phone 7 Applications](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/WP7-Performance.aspx)

[Performance Considerations for Windows Phone 7 Games](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/performance_wp7_games)

**Videos**:

[Optimizing Performance for Silverlight Windows Phone 7 Applications](http://player.microsoftpdc.com/Session/14b74bfd-d2e5-42de-accf-3ff2418783a8)

[Windows Phone 7 Jump Start (Session 17 of 19): Optimizing for Performance](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Windows-Phone-7-Jump-Start-Session-17-of-19-Optimizing-for-Performance)

[Silverlight Firestarter 2010 - Performance Tips for Silverlight Windows Phone 7](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Silverlight-Firestarter/Silverlight-Firestarter-2010-Session-7-Performance-Tips-for-Silverlight-Windows-Phone-7)

**Samples**:

[Creating High Performing Silverlight Applications for Windows Phone Samples](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=3a8636bf-185f-449a-a0ce-83502b9ec0ec)

Comment: I've written a successful app for the iPhone and the only two performance optimization that I had to implement were not to load too much data over the Internet at once and to load the images for a huge list asynchronously. Now I'm implementing the same application for Phone 7 and I had to realize that Phone 7 has a lot of built-in components with performance problems (list box, progress bar, complex layouts etc.). Unfortunately, this question here makes a lot of sense.

Comment: According to the FAQ `Expert programmers interested in professional discussions on software development` this question belongs to programmers. Also mentioned in the FAQ: `I would like to participate in a discussion about ______` should not be asked here...

Comment: This should be a Community Wiki post.  You should also at least have some answers.  FOr an example, see any one of the "Getting Started" pages here on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402466/getting-started-with-windows-phone-7

Comment: It's a good idea to use an automatic code profiler to locate the performance hotspots in your code. For WP7 there is currently only one profiler available, the EQATEC Profiler (http://www.eqatec.com).

Answer (score 1):

**General**

- If your app loads very fast get rid
  off the spash screen.
- Code generation in the compact
  framework is not the same as 
  Windows’ code. Jitter is optimized to
  run fast, not to produce the fastest
  code.
- Property is just a function for .Net
  CF.

**Silverlight**

- Take as much as you can from
  Compositor Thread (for callback
  animations use BitmapCache).
- Use Canvas or custom popup instead of
  default one (Popup class) – lack of
  hardware acceleration.

**XNA**

- Use DXT format for textures and pack
  them into 1 file (faster loading and
  fewer GPU texture switches).
- For things like game stats avoid
  using strings( immutable).
  SpriteBatch.DrawString can take a
  StringBuilder directly for drawing
  text.
- Avoid using/abusing LINQ and foreach
  (it may causes garbage).
     Use Jagged arrays( arrays of arrays) instead of 2d arrays.

Comment: what is custom popup ? and what is callback animation ?

Answer (score 1):

The #1 performance enhancer I've found for my apps, especially for animations that use the UI thread, is to manually set BitmapCache for all UIElements. This significantly improves all animation.

Answer (score -1):

I found this some days ago
[WP7 best practices - Performance](http://wp7dev.wikispaces.com/home#Performance)

Its mostly commented links to articles (some of them mentioned before) and sources (like Jeff Wilcox Performance Progress Bar).

And remember: Listboxes are like kryptonite to WP7 performance =)