# Windows Phone 7 Development guideline

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

Guys I am new to Windows Phone Development in .Net 
Can any one guide me the correct path to start from scratch.
Any links to understand the architecture?

Comment: This might be a good question for [http://programmers.stackexchange.com/](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) as it is more of a meta-programming question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Started with Windows Phone 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402466/getting-started-with-windows-phone-7)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513022/windows-phone-7-mango-development-links/7513428#7513428

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could start with [Windows Phone 7 in 7 Minutes](http://www.msdev.com/Directory/SeriesDescription.aspx?CourseId=158) to get a quick overview, then move onto the [Windows Phone 7 Jumpstart](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/egibson/windows-phone-7-jump-start-session-1-of-12-introduction) series on Channel9 for more depth on individual subject areas.

Comment: You're right, but also http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/ gives a lot help, in particular with Windows Phone Toolkit controls...

Answer (score 2):

there are many sites and this is the link which u can go thru and u'll find many resources available in this.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows-phone-7/info

for understanding the architecture, I think pluralsight is the best one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of information on the Create site, see  http://bit.ly/tpwnyK

Answer (score 1):

I have a Lumia 710 and found a good guide with code snippets that helped me to build an own app for Windows Phone. You might also find it useful. Have a look at it:

http://voip-sip-sdk.com/p_511-windows-phone-platform-voip.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need the .NET framewok http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=65.

The windows mobile development center is always good to get started. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/bb264318

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/windows/introduction-to-windows-mobile-7-development/

Answer (score 0):

Also: http://www.delicious.com/mjfusa/wp7%20gettingstarted

Answer (score 0):

I suggests that you may go through the MSDN pages first:
http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/quickstarts

If you're an experienced Silverlight, WPF, you'll find the following link might be more useful. 
http://wp7dev.wikispaces.com/

Thanks