# Windows phone 7 Mango Development Links

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am new to Windows Phone development.  I am starting by learning C# and Silverlight. Does anybody have any links/resources for learning Windows Phone Mango?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/bb264318

Comment: http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/wp7_jump_start more specific

Comment: btw, this can be found in 1 minute using search. don't be lazy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out these:

- http://indyfromoz.wordpress.com/windows-phone-7-resources/
- http://www.reddit.com/r/wp7dev/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=vs.92).aspx
- http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/06/windows-phone-7-mango-tutorial-24-local.html
- http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/ArticleIndex
- http://www.silverlight.net/
- http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/egibson/windows-phone-7-jump-start-session-1-of-12-introduction
- http://live.visitmix.com/