# Best resource to learn Windows Phone Development?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mobile, windows-phone

I'm looking for online reference / book recommendations, video tutorials, etc...

I've been programming for a while now (Java / Shell), so I don't need a book that spends a lot of effort on basic programming concepts.

All I need is a jump start and some good reference material to clear off my doubts before I start asking more substantial questions on stackoverflow

Comment: Windows Mobile isn't the same as Windows Phone.

Comment: Yes, Edited the question headline. Hope it's clear now.. ;)

Comment: Why do you want to bother learning Windows Mobile then?

Comment: How is this different than this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402466/getting-started-with-windows-phone-7

Comment: Thats too much information, enough for a new guy to get lost in the way.. All I am asking here is a Jump start...

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Programming Windows Phone 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/10/28/free-ebook-programming-windows-phone-7-by-charles-petzold.aspx) BTW, it's free.

[XNA Game Studio 4.0 Programming: Developing for Windows Phone 7 and Xbox 360 (Developer's Library)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672333457)

Comment: This book has been available in pdf as a free download since last year.  If you're like me, and don't want to be scrolling around, it is also available in two volumes on paper.  However, if you have a book reader, and epub or mobi work better for you, MS just released the epub and mobi versions as free downloads as well.

http://www.wpcentral.com/free-ms-ebooks-now-offered-reader-formats

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest [Adam Nathan's 101 Windows Phone 7 Apps](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672335522). This is volume 1 and it deals with writing fully functional apps that you can post on marketplace, as well as explaining key concepts of WP7 programming. I am reading this book at the moment and have to say that I am quite happy that I purchased it.

EDIT: One more suggestion would be to come up with some project, nothing too complex but at the same time nothing too simple and jump into fire head first. You will surely learn a lot if you have a vision for a project. It will drive your forward to succeed.

Answer (score 5):

"Programming Windows Phone 7" by Charles Petzold is worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

I would just recommend the MSDN library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402535%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

Here they have tones of resources and library and some other "need to know" about windows phone 7 development, with sample code, advance practice, and features. Like:
[User Experience Design Guidelines for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202915%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

[Fundamental Concepts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967549%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

[Classes library references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626516%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

[Sample projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

I believe this is what you need to get a jump on developing windows phone.

Answer (score 2):

For me the Design Toolbox helped a lot.

Not only there are really good video tutorials on WP7, you will find some really good presentation about UI designing as well.

http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/default.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I reccomend this video series:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-7-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners

Bob Taylor from the popular Channel 9 is a very helpful tutor that will guide you through how to make apps for Windows Phone. He takes it easy at first so if you know C# and XAML, then you might want to skip ahead. But be sure to do the homework assignments to check on how your doing.
This tutorial will help you a bunch if you don't know a thing about the Windows Phone. I'm on Day 3 right now and, wow. This videos are amazing! I highly reccommend you listen to Bob. He's great, slow, and kinda funny!

**EDIT**

Just saw you have programmed only Java and Shell. If you don't know anything about C# (nudge, nudge), these tutorials were made for people like you

Answer (score 0):

I started here, try to take a look:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402551(v=vs.105).aspx