# set value in other class, get value in other

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I know its kind of stupid question, but I am beginner in C#.
I want to create start page with settings where user can set a values. How I can relay these values to other page ?

Solution that will give me someone will work with IsolatedStorage?
**It does not have**, but it's good to know for the future.

Answer (score 2):

This question unfortunately needs a tutorial as answer. [Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=tutorial%20simple%20windows%20phone%20application%20with%20settings%20page&go=&qs=n&sk=&form=QBLH&filt=all) has many of these:

- [Windows Phone 7 Jump Start Sessions](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/egibson/Windows-Phone-7-Jump-Start-Session-1-of-12-Introduction) (two funny guys show it all!!)
- [Quick Tutorial Page Navigation](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_silverlight/article.php/c18389/) (involving a settings page!)
- [Tutorial Galore](https://blogs.msdn.com/themes/blogs/generic/post.aspx?WeblogApp=lebanon&y=2011&m=01&d=03&WeblogPostName=30-excellent-windows-phone-7-development-tutorials&GroupKeys=)
- [Tips from Stackoverflow for getting started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402466/getting-started-with-windows-phone-7)

Your task involves basic UI design, [page navigation with parameters](http://www.bing.com/search?q=windows%20phone%207%20page%20navigation%20with%20parameters&go=&qs=n&sk=&form=QBLH&filt=all) and/or [data persistence](https://blogs.msdn.com/themes/blogs/generic/post.aspx?WeblogApp=wriju&y=2011&m=07&d=31&WeblogPostName=windows-phone-7-how-save-and-read-file-from-isolated-storage&GroupKeys=).

And you are even allowed to use Google to find these.

Answer (score 0):

If these settings need to be global, then add a static public member variable to the App.xaml.cs file. Set and Get as required from that property.

IsolatedStorage is useful for persisting data when your application closes, but otherwise in Memory persistence via globally accessible properties could be fine for your requirements.