# Windows Phone Development uses wpf?

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am new in windows phone development.

I really have some doubts,

Is WPF is actually using for the windows phone app development ?

I am just confused about to reply to one who ask "Which platform or technology will use for developing windows phone apps ?".

I hope to get a good clear reply here.. I googled it many times. but I didnt get any clear idea yet about this.

Thnks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, WP7 development does not use WPF. It uses Silverlight (or XNA for games).

However, the two are quite closely related. WPF was developed in 2006 and introduced the concepts of bindings, creation of UIs via XAML, visual trees, animation, dependency properties and much more. Many of the WPF concepts were re-used by Silverlight, the web-based plugin. Whilst WPF and Silverlight are similar, they are not the same. Despite this, with a little effort, [code sharing between the two](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/254506/XAMLFinance-A-Cross-platform-WPF-Silverlight-WP7-A) is possible.

See the following question for more references:

[Getting Started with Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402466/getting-started-with-windows-phone-7)

Answer (score 3):

Windows Phone 7 applications can be written using Silverlight or XNA.

With Silverlight you use XAML to create your user interface (as in WPF), but there are couple differences between these 2 technologies: [Contrasting Silverlight and WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921107%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx).