# How to check if a path collection with another path?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I got this code:

```
var intersectionDetail = path1.Data.FillContainsWithDetail(path2.Data);    
if (intersectionDetail != IntersectionDetail.NotCalculated &&
    intersectionDetail != IntersectionDetail.Empty)
{
   //collision
}
```

`.FillContainsWithDetail` only works in wpf, are there any way to do this in Windows Phone?

Comment: This question might be a good starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390101/windows-phone-development-uses-wpf

Comment: Yup i tried it, ".FillContainsWithDetail" is only supported in wpf but not windows phone and thats why im asking what are the alternativ to doing this

Comment: What are you using as the Windows Phone equivalent of `System.Windows.Media.Geometry`?