# Scrape all tiles on wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

This probably isn't possible, and I can't think of a way you could do it... but I thought I would just throw this question out there anyway...

Can anyone think of a way to take some sort of screen shot of every tile on the home screen?

Comment: I don't think so.. :) Android is the old Windows Mobile and Windows phone is new iPhone

Comment: true... my other question was going to be, has anyone seen/tried any USB fingerprint readers? (for a different commercial app)... is there any api in the wp7/silverlight realms for accessing that type of equipment? .... thats probably a no go too :(

Answer (score 0):

Due to the security principles baked into the platforms design. This level of access to information outside of your app is not available.

You'll probably be better off finding out what is possible with the platform (try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402466/getting-started-with-windows-phone-7) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402535%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)), rather than coming up with ideas and then asking questions here about how or if they can be implemented. That is not what StackOverflow is for - see https://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: sorry, its probably the way I asked the question, I was trying to find out if it was possible with the platform... I suppose you're right, you could say the question of implementation was implied.. thanks for the links