# Centralize Windows Phone 8 Resources for developers

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I saw that they have this community wiki list of Windows Phone 7 resources at [Getting Started with Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402466/getting-started-with-windows-phone-7). 
However, I searched but there  isn't one for Windows Phone 8, or did I missed it? 
Would it be possible to create a page like this for Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 development is almost exactly the same as Windows Phone 7 development, especially if you're just starting out.

WP8 has a few differences, and some extra features (e.g. NFC), but overall the links on that page are a great start. The fundamentals are identical, and any examples made for WP7 should work on WP8.