# How to need developing for Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to start learning windows phone and I want to know that for starting this what is need?
what language?

what compiler or program that is for coding?
please tell me about that because I don't know about it and I am noob it.

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-7-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners

Comment: The first necessary skill is solid knowledge of the English language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has a complete guide on this, you can check it out here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680270(v=pandp.11).aspx

Here is another link to a previous question on stackoverflow:

[Getting Started with Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402466/getting-started-with-windows-phone-7?rq=1)

Good Luck