# Windows 7 phone development

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I am a C# dev with most of my experience with windows desktop app. I want to start development on windows 7 phone platform.

Where to start with ? Will it work with VS2008 or i need to have VS 2010 ? how to add the template for phone app development and how to add the win 7 emulator ?

What i need to install to start working on windows 7 phone development ? just downlaoding the SDK will do the work ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Developing apps for Windows Phone 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839120/developing-apps-for-windows-phone-7)

Comment: I would brush up on XAML and Silverlight, which you really need to at least have some understanding of in order to develop anything for on WP7 :)

Answer (score 7):

This [link](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/resources/downloads) will answer your setup/requirements question.

Quote from site:

The Windows Phone Developer Tools Beta includes Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone Beta, the Windows Phone Emulator, XNA Game Studio, Expression Blend for Windows  Phone, samples, and documentation. If Visual Studio 2010 Professional or higher is already installed on your development computer, an add-in for Visual Studio 2010 Professional is automatically installed as well.

**EDIT**

Updated link.

Comment: but i cant find the link for add on ? does it automatically detects ?

Comment: Yes.  Read the last sentence in the answer.

Comment: The tools are no longer in Beta, they are released.  And you should probably get them from the App Hub. http://create.msdn.com

Answer (score 2):

you can get all the free dev tools from [here](http://developer.windowsphone.com/) you don't need a full version of visual studio.

Comment: I aleady have a full version of VS2010. Will it integrate with it or will it add another instance of VS2010 ide

Comment: It will integrate with your existing VS2010, but it will also install the (quite small) express version.

Answer (score 2):

There are two elements to your question:

1. What tools do you need
2. Where do you get the skills you need?

The tools are free, and the links above are fine, though I would probably start [here](http://developer.windowsphone.com/)  In any case, you do need some form of Visual Studio 2010 but we have a free version especially designed for the phone.  All you need besides that are the (free) Windows Phone 7 Developer Tools, though I strongly recommend picking up the documentation and guides.

As for learning WP7 programming, you have many choices. Many of the best are discussed in the [Windows Phone Team Blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/wpdev/rss.aspx).

In addition, we have numerous videos on [Silverlight.net](http://Silverlight.net/learn) and I have an couple of on going mini-tutorial series  (one targeted at Silverlight programmers and one at iPhone Programmers) on [my blog](http://JesseLiberty.com).

There are also lessons, and much more coming out every week.

Best of luck with it and let us know how it goes

-Jesse Liberty
Senior Community Program Manager - Silverlight and Windows Phone 7
Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

The development tools are free with a express edition of visual studio 2010. As far as I know a type of Visual Studio 2010 is required. But if you have VS2010 then you can just download the XNA Gamestudio beta, it comes bundled with all your need to start your Windows Phone 7 development.

For getting started and downloading tools, take a look at this site from microsoft: [Link](http://developer.windowsphone.com/windows-phone-7/)