# Where can I download the Windows Phone Developer tools?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I found the web downloader but they never seem to work for me, how can I download the latest release in an ISO format or a full installer? I cannot use the web downloader. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Developing apps for Windows Phone 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839120/developing-apps-for-windows-phone-7)

Comment: Not a duplicate because this question is asking specifically for an offline installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=201927

(I found this link here: http://www.windowsvalley.com/windows-phone-developer-tools-final-rtw-offline-iso-image-and-training-kit-download-now/)

Answer (score 0):

In the official download page http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=04704acf-a63a-4f97-952c-8b51b34b00ce there is a tiny iso link that point here http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=201927 (yep, they should make it more discoverable).