# How to get the installer of Windows Phone 7 Developer Tool without downloading all the program?

Tags: windows-phone-7

is there anything that I can do?
I download the installer, and then the installer start downloading the thing, but it's 300mb, I would like to download and direct install, so I can get my pendrive and install in a lot of machines.
The link is this one:
http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9713250

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765341/where-can-i-download-the-windows-phone-developer-tools

Answer (score 1):

You can download the ISO file here ([direct link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=201927)). It's at the bottom of [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=04704acf-a63a-4f97-952c-8b51b34b00ce&displaylang=en). You can then burn this ISO, or mount it on a virtual drive.

Comment: This is the 'Release to Web' version, so it's no longer beta. It's the latest SDK, which was released on Sept 16th. This is the same as what your link downloads.